# uniformly convergence of a given series of functions

Tags: real-analysis

I have $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (1-\frac{n}{x}sin(\frac{x}{n}))^\alpha$ with $\alpha \in R$.

I have found pointwise convergence set $E=R-\{-0\}$ if $\alpha>1/2$.

For uniformly convergence I want calculate Sup$_E$ |$f_{n,\alpha}(x)|$.

$f_{n,\alpha}(x)$ are pair so I consider $x>0$. With the substitution $t=x/n$ I have Sup$_{t>0} |1-\frac{sint}{t}|^{\alpha}$.

Is this $Sup >1$?

Comment: Of course, it is $\geq 1$. Let just $t \rightarrow \infty$, then $1- \sin(t)/t \rightarrow 1$.